# Variable outputting same result on different conditions

Tags: php

First question: For the case where the device_id is 2 the output is two, but any other case the output is still 2. Why is this?

```
if ($line == "IMEI 358998018395510\r\n"){
     $device_id = 1;
     }elseif($line == "IMEI 352924028650492\r\n"){
     $device_id = 3;
     }else {
     $device_id = 2;
}
```

Second question: I would like to replace the else statement above with the following:

```
..
elseif ($line == "$GPVTG,0,T,0,M,0,N,0,K,A*23\r\n"){
    $device_id = 2;
}
```

but the problem is that, the parser is faulting part of the string above picking out "$GPVTG" as undefined. Thought it should treat it as a whole string because it is in quotes?

Comment: try echoing $line before the if statement to see if it's what you think it is.

Comment: This question is formatted in so ugly pattern. I dont want to waste my time with this.

Answer (score 3):

1. None of your conditions match, so it falls through to the else clause.
2. Double quotes allow variable substitution. Escape the `$` or use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP variables written in double quotes are evaluated at run time, and `$` is used to represent the variable so you need to escape the `$` in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I could do the following and decided to use it.  It works just fine.  Thanks for all your contributions.

```
switch ($lineTokens[0]){
                case "IMEI 358998018395510\r\n":
                    $device_id = 1;
                    break;
                case "IMEI 352924028650492\r\n":
                    $device_id = 3;
                    break;
                case '$GPVTG':
                    $device_id = 2;
                    break;

            }
```

Just to add: Similar to what some have suggested,  I had to determine when to use single or double quotes as in the last CASE statement, escaping them when necessary.  I used $linetokens instead of $line as previously submitted after exploding the $line. This enabled me to only find a match for '$GPVTG' instead of the whole $line which is not unique.